# Group By in linq in the following structure

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have two list ( User Permissions and previleges)

```
UserPermission 
{
   int UserId;
   int permissionId;
   int privelegeId;
   string ObjectName;

}

Privelege
{
   int privelegeId;
   int Name;

}
```

I want all the privelege related to a particular user for a particular objectName .

So the final structure i want to achieve using linq is 
       {
         objectName: ""
         Previlages []
       }

Comment: You woukd need a join by privelegeId and a group by UserId.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var query = from user in userPer
                    from pre in privelages
                    where user.privelegeId == pre.privelegeId
                    group new { user, pre } by user.UserId;
```

Here is the working [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lrOPDh).